# How to confirm if AWS server is started and from what boot level?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have an amazon ec2 instance which is attached to a 8gb volume.
The instance is shown running and the volume is attached.

After october update my site stopped working with connection refused error on chrome.

I contacted aws support and they asked me to **"Would you be able to confirm if your Web Server is started and also started from boot level?"**

How can i confirm this after login in to aws console ?

Pardon if this question is too basic as i am pretty new to aws.

OS linux.EBS backed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you would confirm that like in any other system: log in to the guest OS and check if the service is started.

You are not even telling what guest OS are you running, so it's difficult to give you directions here. On Windows, look for IIS. On Linux, look for Apache. On both, check if TCP port 80 is listening, unless you are running your web server on a nonstandard port.

Comment: I logged in through ssh and checked for services my httpd service was not started so i started it. Since i rebooted the server before so i took it for granted that my service is running.

Answer (score 0):

One big thing to keep in mind is that the IP address of your AWS instance can change.  Given that you stated an "october update" it sounds like the server might have been rebooted at that time, and if so then that's the kind of event that can cause the IP address to change.  Make sure you are using the public IP address or the DNS name of the instance to access it.

If you have set up your own DNS for your instance then it should be a CNAME record to the DNS name of the instance and not an A record containing the IP address of the server.  By using a CNAME you're ensuring your DNS is updated properly if the IP address of your AWS instance changes.

Comment: I use a elastic IP which is associated with my instance .I use this elastic IP in my CNAME